# Glassfish login server error issue,

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, server-error

I'm having a log in error when I try to login to the glassfish server. I have tried it on another system: it works fine, but not on my laptop.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Arwel>cd C:\Program Files\glassfish

C:\Program Files\glassfish>cd bin

C:\Program Files\glassfish\bin>asadmin start-domain
java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for C:\Program Files\glassfish\glassfish\
domains\domain1\logs\server.log
        at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger.addLogFileHandler(
GFLauncherLogger.java:100)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncher.setup(GFLauncher.java:18
9)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.StartDomainCommand.createLauncher(StartD
omainCommand.java:209)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.StartDomainCommand.executeCommand(StartD
omainCommand.java:107)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:264)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AsadminMain.executeCommand(AsadminMain.j
ava:306)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:238)
Waiting for domain1 to start ...................................................
.............Error starting domain domain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
ERROR: Unable to create cache directory: C:\Program Files\glassfish\glassfish\do
mains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix
ERROR: Error creating bundle cache. (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to creat
e cache directory.)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create cache directory.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.<init>(BundleCache.java:
131)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:629)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.r
un(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:88)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.osgi.framework.Bu
ndleException: Error creating bundle cache.
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.r
un(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:90)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error creating bundle cache.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:634)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.r
un(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create cache directory.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.<init>(BundleCache.java:
131)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:629)
        ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMa
in.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException: java.lang.NullPointerExc
eption
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:164)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime
.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.
java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(
GlassFishMain.java:112)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.newFramework(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:230)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:133)
        ... 9 more
Error stopping framework: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher$1.run(G
lassFishMain.java:203)

Command start-domain failed.

C:\Program Files\glassfish\bin>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you don't have the permissions to write to the `Program Files` folder. You might try again with administator privileges.

You can start the cmd as administator like this:

- Press start
- Type "cmd"
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: thanks for the help unwichtich it worked.

Comment: I just want to point out that this isn't a good long-term solution to the problem that you are running into... as you get closer to sharing your work with a wider audience, you should set up a domain that is not being executed by a server running with admin privileges.